# Is there a function in pandas to align rows with matching identifiers and fill voids with NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a function in pandas that aligns data wrt to a different columns.  For example, I have four columns, two times and two are identifiers.

```
id    time    id    time

a ,    1:10,    a ,    1:11

a ,    1:12 ,   a  ,   1:13

b  ,   1:13    c ,    1:15

c ,    1:14  

d ,    1:15
```

I would like to match the rows with id `c` to each other and get the following:

```
id  time  id  time 

a ,  1:10,  a ,  1:11

a ,  1:12,  a ,  1:13

b ,  1:13,  NaN, NaN

c,   1:14,   c  , 1:15

d ,  1:15,  NaN, NaN
```

I have my data in a dataframe with respective labels.  I have tried loops to find matches and reindexing, but run into errors. I can potentially have thousands of entries, with numerous missing points.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'Error Time':array1[:,0],'Err ID':array1[:,1],'Alert 
Type':array1[:,2]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'Recover Time':array2[:,0], 'Rec ID':array2[:,1]}) 
data_array = pd.concat([A,B], axis=1) #Joins the two arrays together
pd.to_datetime(data_array['Error Time'],format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time
pd.to_datetime(data_array['Recover Time'],format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.time

#data_array = data_array.sort_values(by=['Error Time'])
col_size = len(data_array['Error Time'])
for i in range(col_size):
    if data_array.iloc[i,1] == data_array.iloc[i,3]:
        indexA.append(i)
    else:
        for j in range(col_size):
            if data_array.iloc[i,1] == data_array.iloc[j,3]:
                if indexA.count(j) > 0:
                    j = j + 1
                else:
                    indexA.append(j)
                    break
for k in range(col_size):
    if indexA.count(k)== 0:
        indexA.append(k)
data_array = data_array.reindex(['Error Time', 'Error ID', 'Alert 
Type],index=[indexA])
```

Comment: Try look at merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['a','a','b','c','d'],'Time':['1:10','1:12','1:13','1:14','1:15']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['a','a','c'],'Time':['1:11','1:13','1:15']})

A = df1.assign(C=df1.groupby('ID').cumcount())
B = df2.assign(C=df2.groupby('ID').cumcount())

A.merge(B, on=['ID', 'C'], how='outer').drop('C', 1)
```

Out:

```
    ID  Time_x  Time_y
0   a   1:10    1:11
1   a   1:12    1:13
2   b   1:13    NaN
3   c   1:14    1:15
4   d   1:15    NaN
```

Comment: This method allowed the times in 'Time_y' column to reflect what I needed. The first method pulled down the time from the previous row, instead of using the next correct row.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wen said, [`pandas.Merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is the way I would approach this.

For your problem it would look something like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', '1:10'],
    ['a', '1:12'],
    ['b', '1:13'],
    ['c', '1:14'],
    ['d', '1:15'],
], columns=['id', 'time'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', '1:11'],
    ['a', '1:13'],
    ['c', '1:14'],
], columns=['id', 'time'])

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
```

df3 after merge will look like this

```
    id  time_x  time_y
0   a   1:10    1:11
1   a   1:10    1:13
2   a   1:12    1:11
3   a   1:12    1:13
4   b   1:13    NaN
5   c   1:14    1:14
6   d   1:15    NaN
```

`pandas.merge` works like SQL joins and for your example you would choose `how='left'` which is equivalent to a left-outer SQL join. We'll need to drop the rows that get duplicated to achieve your desired output. You can do this with [`pandas.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). The `reset_index` will just start the index count from zero again, it is optional.

`df4 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'time_x']).reset_index(drop=True)`

This will yield

```
    id  time_x  time_y
0   a   1:10    1:11
1   a   1:12    1:11
2   b   1:13    NaN
3   c   1:14    1:14
4   d   1:15    NaN
```